# Python Pandas: Best way to find local maximums in large DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

I have a large dataframe that consitsts of many cycles, each cycle has 2 maximum peak values inside that I need to capture into another dataframe.

I have created a sample data frame that mimics the data I am seeing:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Cycle':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 'Pressure':[100,110,140,180,185,160,120,110,189,183,103,115,140,180,200,162,125,110,196,183,100,110,140,180,185,160,120,180,201,190]}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As you can see in each cycle there are two maxes but the part I was having trouble with was that the 2nd peak is usaully higher than the first peak, so there could be rows of numbers technicially higher than the other peaks max in the cycle. The results should look something like this:

```
data2 = {'Cycle':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 'Peak Maxs': [185,189,200,196,185,201]}

df2= pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

I have tried a couple methods including .nlargest(2) per cycle, but the problem is that since one of the peaks is usually higher it will pull the 2nd highest number in the data, which isnt necesssarily the other peak.

This graph shows the peak pressures from each cycle that I would like to be able to find.
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `scipy` `argrelextrema`

```
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
out = df.groupby('Cycle')['Pressure'].apply(lambda x : x.iloc[argrelextrema(x.values, np.greater)])
Out[124]: 
Cycle    
1      4     185
       8     189
2      14    200
       18    196
3      24    185
       28    201
Name: Pressure, dtype: int64

out = out.sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(2).sort_index() 
out
Out[138]: 
Cycle    
1      4     185
       8     189
2      14    200
       18    196
3      24    185
       28    201
Name: Pressure, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah, that's how you use `signal`. I was trying to play with `find_peaks` but `scipy.signal.find_peaks` keeps falling for me....

Comment: @QuangHoang find_peaks(df['Pressure'].values)[0], return two peak and properties, we seems just need the peak ~ :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang Like `df.groupby('Cycle')['Pressure'].apply(lambda x : x.iloc[find_peaks(x.values)[0]])
`

Comment: I know, and TIL `argrextrema` as well. I was referring to the fact that using `scipy.signal.argreextrema` straight-up is not working for me. I needed to do like you `from scipy.signal import ...`.

Comment: @QuangHoang ah , scipy and numpy toolbox have the same 'issue'

Comment: When using this method on my actual data, it is pulling up more than 2 peaks per cycle, is there any way to limit this value to only select the 2 highest peaks it finds per each cycle?

Comment: @SeanK22 after above out = out.sort_values().groupby(level=0).tail(2).sort_index()

Comment: could you edit your comment to include that? Im not sure exactly where you are telling me to place it. Sorry I am very new with python

Comment: Thanks so much! this worked

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby().shift()` to get the neighborhood values, then compare:

```
g = df.groupby('Cycle')

local_maxes = (df['Pressure'].gt(g['Pressure'].shift())    # greater than previous row
               & df['Pressure'].gt(g['Pressure'].shift(-1))] # greater than next row
               )

df[local_maxes]
```

Output:

```
    Cycle  Pressure
4       1       185
8       1       189
14      2       200
18      2       196
24      3       185
28      3       201
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i applied this to my data i got this: <ipython-input-80-ed26ba949dab>:51: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
  df3[local_maxes]